# How to modify a momentjs calendar to have weeks start on a user-specified day?

Tags: javascript, configuration, calendar, momentjs

I am writing an app with AngularJS 1.5. I am using the momentJS library for my date/time.

I have made a calendar.

I made the calendar by determing the number of ISO weeks in a month and then filling out each week with the 7 days in that ISO week.

I want to do it like that so I can show the few trailing days in the previous and next month.

It works great but now I am tasked with the user being able to configure the starting day of the week (e.g. Mon, Sun or Sat).

I am not sure if I can still use these ISO weeks for my task. I want it to be locale/language independent.

Here is my JS fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/aubz88/ge5q9z5t/9/#&togetherjs=HzJkCK0BPy

Here is a code snippet:

```
var data = {};
data.weeks = {};
data.currentCalendarMonth = moment().startOf('month');

buildMonth();

function buildMonth() {

    data.weeks = {};
    var startOfMonthISOWeek = data.currentCalendarMonth.clone().startOf('month').isoWeek();
    var endOfMonthISOWeek = data.currentCalendarMonth.clone().endOf('month').isoWeek();

    for (var i = startOfMonthISOWeek; i < endOfMonthISOWeek + 1; i++) {
        data.weeks[i] = [];
        buildWeek(i);
    }
}

function buildWeek(isoWeekNumber) {

    var start = moment().year(data.currentCalendarMonth.get('year')).week(isoWeekNumber).startOf('isoweek');
    var firstDayOfTheWeek = start.clone();

    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        var day = firstDayOfTheWeek.clone().startOf('day').add(i, 'days');

        data.weeks[isoWeekNumber].push({
            date: day.get('date'),
            month: day.get('month'),
            year: day.get('year'),
            day: day
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`week()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/) ans `startOf('week')` instead of [`isoWeek()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-week/) and `startOf('week')`.

[`week()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/):

> Gets or sets the week of the year.
>
> Because different locales define week of year numbering differently, Moment.js added `moment#week` to get/set the localized week of the year.
>
> The week of the year varies depending on which day is the first day of the week (Sunday, Monday, etc), and which week is the first week of the year.

This way your calendar will depend on locale. You can customize the first day of the week (for the current locale) using `updateLocale` method, just change the value of `dow` (day of week) key (and `doy` key too, if needed) of the week object. See [Customize](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/) section of the docs to get more info about locale customization.

If you need, you can also define a [pseudo locale](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/pseudo-locale/).

Comment: I'm not sure if in my situation the calendar should be locale-dependent. It has a default and then the user will configure it.

Comment: @user1261710 see the last part of my answer, if you don't need to change the full locale, you can create a [pseudo locale](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/pseudo-locale/) just to have a configurable start of the week.

Comment: I tried this approach but it only works for Sunday and Monday. For example,             moment.updateLocale(moment.locale(), {
              dow: 2
            }); I would expect to see Tuesday as the first day but it chose Sunday instead.

Comment: @user1261710 Note that `dow` is a key of the `week` object, you should use something like: `moment.updateLocale(moment.locale(), { week:{dow: 2} });`and this should be the first line of your code.

Comment: Thanks very much, that worked. Is there a way to undo the changes to the locale?

Comment: What do you mean with undo the changes? You can get locale settings using [`localeData`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) and save it into a variable, then `updateLocale` back with original values.

Comment: When the first day of the week is Sat 01,01,2018 is found to be week 52 but in 2017 not 2018. What can I do, this is wrong? console.log(data.currentCalendarMonth.clone().startOf('month').format('YYYY w DD MM')); 2018 52 01 01